# Java EE6, EJB 3.1 and Socket Client

Tags: sockets, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I'm developing a web application that needs to communicate with any servers (python) by socket. My web application will be the client socket.

I read some alternatives about EJB and Socket. (JCA was indicated, but it is too much for my simple client)

To simplify the solution I was thinking to create an EJB @Singleton and create Threads to work in it.

Do you have some suggestion?

My simple idea:

Singleton

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class SingletonBean {
    private List<EventMonitor> monitors = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        EventMonitor monitor = new EventMonitor("192.168.1.1", 23);
        monitors.add(monitor);
        monitor.start();

        monitor = new EventMonitor("192.168.1.2", 23);
        monitors.add(monitor);
        monitor.start();
    }
}
```

Monitor

```
public class EventMonitor extends Thread {

    private String host;
    private int port;

    public EventMonitor(final String host, final int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;

        openConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // read socket message and persist
        // I think persist here is not a good idea, any better idea?
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, the answer was simple like the idea!

Singleton was enough in this case.